# I wanted to associate two different collection of mongodb and mongoose using the aggregate $lookup function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

My code compiles successfully as I m not getting any error. But the array which I wanted to aggregate with the field of other collection is still empty.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const user = require('../schema');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  user.db1.aggregate([{
      $lookup: {
        from: 'db2',
        localField: 'fullname',
        foreignField: 'skills',
        as: 'user_Details'
      }
    }

  ]).exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("getting user data from database")
    res.send(data)
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Usually there is a typo. Can you provide an example case of your database (probably one document from each collection is sufficient)?

Comment: const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid:{type:String},
    fullname:{type:String},
    phone:{type:Number},
    email:{type:String},
        
})
const skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid:{type:Number},
    skills:{type:String},

Comment: this is how i described type in  schema.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what have you meant by writing `user.db1.aggregate(...)`? What is `user.db1`? The syntax I'm aware of would be just `user.aggregate(...` where `user` is the associated model.

Comment: agree with what u said but in the schema i have exported models as db1:users,therefore here i have imported schema in a constant named as user and from there i m using db1 as a model.

Comment: also i tried writing only user.aggregate but it did not work,the resultant array is still the same.kindly suggest me something else if possible to associate the two collections successfully.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot `$lookup` 2 different databases. Is this such a case?

Comment: no i m using single database inside which there are two collections named  users  and skills ,then i want to assosicate these collections using the common field they have i.e.'userid'.that is why i was using aggregate and $lookup